# Is there any good algorithm implementation to detect similar images?

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing

There are a lot of algorithms talking about how to detect similar images. Is there any actual implementation in any language (but preferably in C/C++) that detects similar images?

Answer (score 4):

I personally haven't used this library, but you might want to check out [OpenCV.](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) It seems to be a very good open-source image library and is supported in C++, C, Python, and soon Java.

Also, [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/imgproc_object_detection.html) looks like a function that you might want to check out for image similarity if you choose to go with this library.

Hope you find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Opencv is a good toolkit - but there isn't a single solution because it depends what you mean by the **same** image.

Do you want to find resized / rescaled / rotated copies of the same same image? in which case a colour histogram is probably a good approach

Or do you want to find different pictures of the same object? In which case you need a feature / line extraction and some sort of matching criterion

Comment: yes, resized / rescaled / rotated copies can be identified.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to Check Image Magick http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/